# What does it mean "must declare scalar variable" error in C# form?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I tried to update form but get error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@isyeri".

My code and SQL Server table code is below.

```
 using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=sqloledb;SERVER=NEVZAT-PC;DATABASE=DENEME;User ID=sa;password=sapass;"))
 using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("update istakip set isyeri=@isyeri,isaciklama=@isaciklama,durum=@durum,personel=@personel,tarih=@tarih,baslamasaati=@baslamasaati,netsure=@netsure,kullanilanmalzeme=@kullanilanmalzeme,isbolum=@isbolum,arizatanim=@arizatanim,isemrino=@isemrino,kadi=@kadi where id=@id)", con))
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isyeri", comboBox1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isaciklama", textBox2.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@durum", comboBox2.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personel", comboBox3.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarih", dateTimePicker1.Value);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baslamasaati", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString());//veritabanında varchar türünde bu
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@netsure", textBox3.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kullanilanmalzeme", textBox4.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbolum", comboBox4.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arizatanim", comboBox5.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isemrino", textBox5.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kadi", label13.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);

     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
}
```

and my SQL Server table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[istakip]
(
    [id] [numeric](5, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [isyeri] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [isaciklama] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [durum] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [personel] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tarih] [datetime] NULL,
    [baslamasaati] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [netsure] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [kullanilanmalzeme] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [isbolum] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [arizatanim] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [isemrino] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [kadi] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

Comment: Providing your sa-password on a public site is not the best idea

Comment: iirc OleDbCommand requires unnamed parameters so use ordinal `?` characters instead of @names (or if your using just MSSQL use System.Data.SqlClient)

Comment: @AlexK.: but shouldn't it also work if you use `@` and the positions are correct?

Comment: I don't think so, the server sees the @isyeri token & thinks is an undeclared variable because it wasn't substituted within the command.

Comment: positions correct.you can check

Comment: You can see the code.what is wrong with the code?ı declare @isyeri

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: See the duplicate. The exception text is the different because the platform is different but the cause is the same.

Comment: dont use AddWithValue, it can produce exact these kind of problems. See this https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: what do you suggest my friend?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is some of your parameter value are null. When you use null values for parameters you must set them to `DBNull`, otherwise the parameter will not be passed to the SQL statement:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isyeri", ((object) comboBox1.Text ?? DBNull.Value));
```

That said, I do not think the `Text` property of a `ComboBox` can be null, but it's a good habit to get into when dealing with SQL parameters.

Comment: sorry but didn't work.it says cannot be applied

Comment: @nevzataltıparmak - you need to cast to object so they are the same type (see answer update). This is the answer you are looking for though, I am searching for a duplicate because I know I have seen this before on [so].

Answer (score 1):

Reference to following link:

[MSDN Link for OleDBCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2)

For the case of OleDbCommand:

Change `@` with `?` and use same sequence for adding parameter.

As said in the comment by @Igor, both symbols can be used. Check below parameters adding for OleDb. Also it seems you need to cast cell value into integer for the `@id` parameter.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(
        "@isyeri", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox1.Text;
//...

cmd.Parameters.Add(
        "@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
```

Comment: Although `?` can be used so can `@pname` although the ordinal position is the only thing that matters in either case. The error above is not caused by the name of the parameter or the position as the positions in the parameter collection match the position in the statement.